# How to get n rows of records of given m ids in Mysql by id desc

Tags: mysql

Suppose i have a table like this

```
id | user_id | rating 

1  | 500     | 5

2  | 501     | 3

3  | 500     | 5

4  | 502     | 4

5  | 502     | 1
```

How can i write a mysql query to find the last 10 records for each id of given three ids (500, 501,502) by id desc

Comment: What version of mysql are you on.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Show input data and expected result.

Comment: is id column is unique ?

Comment: What is last here, there is no natural order in a sql table?

Comment: 'last 10 records of given three ids (500, 501,502)' - is open to interpretation, do you mean 10 for each of 500,501,502 ie 30 or 10 for 500,501,502 combined?

Comment: @P.Salmon My Mysql version is 5.7 and i need 10 last row for each given id.

Comment: @MangeshAuti id column is auto incremented

Answer (score 1):

assuming your id is an auto increment column  and the three ids (500, 501,502) are for user_id 
then you could use

```
 select  * 
 from my_table  
 where user_id in  (500, 501,502) 
 order by  id desc 
 limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Being a bit lazy here's a way to get the last 2 per user_id by using a variable to allocate a row number joined to the max occurrences per user

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T
(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, USER_ID INT, RATING INT);
INSERT INTO T (USER_ID,RATING) VALUES
(500,1),
(502,1),
(500,2),(500,3),
(502,2),
(600,1);

SELECT U.*
FROM
(
SELECT S.ID,S.USER_ID,S.RATING,
         T.MAXROWS
FROM
(
SELECT ID,USER_ID,RATING,   
         IF(USER_ID <> @P,@R:=1,@R:=@R+1) RN,
         @P:=USER_ID
FROM T
ORDER BY USER_ID ASC,ID ASC
) S 
JOIN 
(SELECT USER_ID,COUNT(*) MAXROWS FROM T GROUP BY USER_ID) T ON T.USER_ID = S.USER_ID
) U
WHERE U.RATING > U.MAXROWS - 2 AND U.USER_ID IN(500,502);

 +----+---------+--------+---------+
| ID | USER_ID | RATING | MAXROWS |
+----+---------+--------+---------+
|  3 |     500 |      2 |       3 |
|  4 |     500 |      3 |       3 |
|  2 |     502 |      1 |       2 |
|  5 |     502 |      2 |       2 |
+----+---------+--------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL operator to get 10 result of each id

```
(select * from test
 where user_id =500
 order by id desc 
 limit 10)

UNION ALL

(select * from test
 where user_id =501
 order by id desc 
 limit 10)

UNION ALL

(select * from test
 where user_id =502
 order by id desc 
 limit 10)

 order by id desc;
```

Check here for [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/62GRigZsjdo2wC6NbZyRap/3)

**NOTE:** Reviewer are welcome to enhance or improve the query.

Comment: This will give the correct result but what happened if you provide 500 ids?  I am looking for more efficient query